# How to query sql on django by user for a model function

Tags: python, sql, django

In one of my models, I am trying to query the django sql for entries by user to utilize in a function for one of the model objects.
How can I successfully query from sql in the biography model to utilize in a function of the journal model for the prompt method object?

The below code is what I am trying but doesn't generate any searches for the function:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
import misaka


# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Biography(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='biography',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256,default="")
    prompt_html = models.CharField(max_length=256,editable=False,default="")
    entry = models.TextField(default="")
    entry_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
```

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    def gen_prompt():

        def sort_by_auth_user(self, item):
            if item.created_by == self.request.user:
                return -1
            else:
                return 1

        def get_queryset(self):

            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute('SELECT entry FROM journal_Biography')
                journal_str = cursor.fetchall()
                sorted_journal_str = sorted(journal_str, key=self.sort_by_auth_user)
                journal_str = str(sorted_journal_str)
                qg = TextGenerator(output_type="question")
                gen_prompt = qg.predict([journal_str])
                return gen_prompt


    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='journal',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=256,default=gen_prompt())
    prompt_html = models.CharField(max_length=256,editable=False,default=gen_prompt())
    entry = models.TextField(default='')
    entry_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
```

Comment: What are you trying to query there?

Comment: I am trying to query the entry object within the biography class, which is input from the user.